# How can I sort a column that contains number and image using datatable

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

How can I sort the second column that contain image and number.

```
<table id='tb' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td><img src='edit.png'>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td><img src='edit.png'>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td><img src='edit.png'>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried like this,because of that image it sorting as 1,10,11,12..If I remove that image tag it sorting properly.So kindly give some solution.

```
$("#tb").dataTable({
    "order": [
        [1, "asc"]
    ]
});
```

Comment: **[This should help you up with](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4526/how-to-sort-a-column-with-images)**

Comment: You can remove `img` tags, and try to add this image using something like `:before` CSS rules. In general, it is better than copying this `img` to the every cell; and it will sort your columns properly.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the image tag, it is sorting as a string. It will start sorting with the first text it sees though, so the way i get around this is by appending a hidden span with the numerical value. You just have to remember to make all the values of same length since they will still be sorted as strings. You can do this by appending 0's.

An example [assuming i know that my number will never be over 100]:

```
<td><span style="display:none">024</span><img src='edit.png'>24</td>
...
<td><span style="display:none">001</span><img src='edit.png'>1</td>
...
<td><span style="display:none">033</span><img src='edit.png'>33</td>
...
<td><span style="display:none">051</span><img src='edit.png'>51</td>
```

An ascending sort, even as a string, will result in 1, 24, 33, 51

Comment: This is a very clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is much more flexible in the current version of dataTables with the inclusion of [HTML5 data attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html).

Attaching data-sort or data-order attributes to the td tag allows you to customize sort order for all types of dom objects in your tables.

```
<table id='tb' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td data-order='1'><img src='edit.png'>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td data-order='2'><img src='edit.png'>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>status</td>
        <td data-order='3'><img src='edit.png'>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I started writing that this may not work in a dynamic setting (where the data is coming from DB), but IIUYC, you mean just put the same "value" in the data-order attribute as well, and the data tables will use the data-order attribute instead of the cell content.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Guruprasad Rao comment and the plugin docs (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#hidden_title_string), you have to create your own filter. Something like this:

Filter code:

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-inner-text'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return td.text();
    } );
}
```

Then in the datatable init function:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "columns": [
        null,
        { "orderDataType": "dom-inner-text" },
        ....
    ]
} );
```

Comment: This is probably the most general solution, but it appears that two answers by scottysmalls can solve this particular situation more simply.